# STM32F411RE: I want to turn on the LED in open-drain mode, but the LED doesn't turn on

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I want to turn on the LED on the microcontroller with open-drain mode, but the LED doesn't turn on.
So far I have this, I don't know what my mistake is. I am working with STM32F411RE in STMCubeIDE.

```
#include "main.h"

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

#define RCC_BASE_ADDRESS 0x40023800
#define GPIOA_BASE_ADDRESS 0x40020000

#define RCC_AHB1ENR_OFFSET 0x30
#define GPIOA_MODER_OFFSET 0x00
#define GPIOA_ODR_OFFSET 0x14
#define GPIOA_OTYPER_OFFSET 0x04

#define RCC_AHB1ENR_POINTER (uint32_t*)(RCC_BASE_ADDRESS + RCC_AHB1ENR_OFFSET)
#define GPIOA_MODER_POINTER (uint32_t*)(GPIOA_BASE_ADDRESS + GPIOA_MODER_OFFSET)
#define GPIOA_ODR_POINTER (uint32_t*)(GPIOA_BASE_ADDRESS + GPIOA_ODR_OFFSET)
#define GPIOA_OTYPER_POINTER (uint32_t*)(GPIOA_BASE_ADDRESS + GPIOA_OTYPER_OFFSET)

int main(void)
{
 HAL_Init();
SystemClock_Config();
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();

*RCC_AHB1ENR_POINTER |= (1 << 0);  // Enable clock for GPIOA
*GPIOA_MODER_POINTER |= (1 << 10); // Set pin 5 as output
*GPIOA_OTYPER_POINTER |= (1 << 5); // Set pin 5 to open-drain mode
*GPIOA_ODR_POINTER &= ~(1 << 5);   // Turn on the LED by driving the pin low (since it's open-drain)

while(1) {}
}
```

Comment: You may need to delay between enabling the clock for GPIOA and trying to set its registers.

Comment: You should also use `volatile` in your register definitions. Or better yet, use the definitions from CMSIS for your chip, e.g. `GPIO_TypeDef` etc, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Agree about volatile (and everything really), but also lack of volatile may also cause compiler to rearrange certain instructions. There is a chance that you (OP) provide clock to GPIO already after you write some config to it, not before. Those GPIO configurations look like completely independent, not interlocked operations on non-volatiles, so the compiler is free to switch the order, if I'm not mistaken. What does the debugger tell you about the content of GPIO registers?